# Find $P(X<Y)$ if $X$ and $Y$ are independent with $X\thicksim\text{Geom}(p)$ and $Y\thicksim\text{Geom}(q)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification

**The Problem:** Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $X\thicksim\text{Geom}(p),$ and $Y\thicksim\text{Geom}(q)$. Find $P(X<Y)$. [Hint: Break the event into smaller pieces.]

**My Attempt:** Recall that $P(X=k)=p(1-p)^{k-1}$ and $P(Y=n)=q(1-q)^{n-1}$ for all $k,n\in\mathbb N$, where we assume that $0<p,q<1$. Following the hint, we note that 
$\{X<Y\}=\bigcup_{1\leq k<n,n\in\mathbb N}\{X=k,Y=n\}$ is a union of pairwise disjoint events. To see the set equality, note that if $(\omega_1,\omega_2)\in\{X<Y\}$ then there is $k,n\in\mathbb N$ with $k<n$ 
such that $X(\omega_1)=k<Y(\omega_2)=n$, so it follows that $(\omega_1,\omega_2)\in\bigcup_{1\leq k<n,n\in\mathbb N}\{X=k,Y=n\}.$ Now let 
$(\omega_1,\omega_2)\in\bigcup_{1\leq k<n,n\in\mathbb N}\{X=k,Y=n\}$. Then there $X(\omega_1)=k$ and $Y(\omega_2)=n$ for some $k,n\in\mathbb N$ with $k<n$, so that 
$(\omega_1,\omega_2)\in\{X<Y\}.$ That the sets are pairwise disjoint is clear since for $i\ne j$ we have that $\bigcup_{1\leq k<i}\{X=k,Y=i\}$ and $\bigcup_{1\leq k<j}\{X=k,Y=j\}$ 
are disjoint because if $(\omega_1,\omega_2)\in\bigcup_{1\leq k<i}\{X=k,Y=i\}$ then $X(\omega_1)=k$ and $Y(\omega_2)=i\ne j$ so that 
$(\omega_1,\omega_2)\notin\bigcup_{1\leq k<j}\{X=k,Y=j\}$, and similarly for the other direction.
By the countable additivity of the probability measure and the independence of the random variables $X$ and $Y$ it follows that
\begin{equation*}\begin{split}
P(X<Y)&=P\left(\bigcup_{1\leq k<n,n\in\mathbb N}\{X=k,Y=n\}\right)=\sum_{1\leq k<n,n\in\mathbb N}P(X=k,Y=n)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}P(X=k)P(Y=n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}p(1-p)^{k-1}q(1-q)^{n-1}\\
&=pq\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-q)^{n-1}\frac{1-(1-p)^{n-1}}{p}=q\sum_{n=1}^\infty(1-q)^{n-1}(1-(1-p)^{n-1})\\
&=1-q\sum_{n=1}^\infty[(1-q)(1-p)]^{n-1}=1-\frac{q}{1-(1-p)(1-q)}\\
&=\frac{1-(1-p)(1-q)-q}{1-(1-p)(1-q)}\\
&=\frac{p(1-q)}{p+q-pq}.
\end{split}\end{equation*}

---

Do you agree with my attempt at a solution to this problem?

Any feedback is much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Minor corrections: \begin{equation*}\begin{split}
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}P(X=k)P(Y=n)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}p(1-p)^{k-1}q(1-q)^{n-1}\\
&=pq\sum_{n=2}^\infty (1-q)^{n-1}\frac{1-(1-p)^{n-1}}{p}=q\sum_{n=2}^\infty(1-q)^{n-1}(1-(1-p)^{n-1})\\
&=[1-q]-q\sum_{n=2}^\infty[(1-q)(1-p)]^{n-1}=[1-q]-\frac{q(1-q)(1-p)}{1-(1-p)(1-q)}\\
&=\frac{(1-q)(1-p)[1-2q]}{1-(1-p)(1-q)}.
\end{split}\end{equation*}

Comment: You should be able to radically streamline this by making use of the hint— i.e. both r.v.s are the waiting times associated with Bernoulli processes... you may want to first consider by analogy the easier problem of first arrival with exponential Y and X.  That problem can be solved with poisson splitting and merging... your problem is the same except you need to manage ‘collisions’.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake. I calculated the following: $$\begin{equation*}\begin{split}&\quad(1-q)[1-(1-p)(1-q)]-q(1-q)(1-p)\\&=1-q-(1-q)[1-q-p+pq]-q+q^2+pq-pq^2\\&=1-2q+q^2+pq-pq^2-1+q+p-pq+q-q^2-pq+pq^2\\&=p-pq\\&=p(1-q).\end{split}\end{equation*}$$

Comment: @GtheStackman you are absolutely right, i made the mistake in the last subtraction. Your answer is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an alternative route based on the hint.

Let $B_1,B_2,\cdots,C_1,C_2,\dots$ be independent random variables such that $B_i\sim\mathsf{Bernoulli}(p)$ and $C_i\sim\mathsf{Bernoulli}(q)$.

Then let $X:=\min\{n\mid B_n=1\}$ and $Y:=\min\{n\mid C_n=1\}$ so that $X$ and $Y$ are independent with $X\sim\mathsf{Geom}(p)$ and $Y\sim\mathsf{Geom}(q)$.

Then: $$\{X<Y\}=\{B_1=1,C_1=0\}\cup\{B_1=0=C_1,X<Y\}$$ so that:$$P(X<Y)=P(B_1=1,C_1=0)+P(B_1=0=C_1)P(X<Y\mid B_1=0=C_1)=$$$$p(1-q)+(1-p)(1-q)P(X<Y)$$and leading to:$$P(X<Y)=\frac{p(1-q)}{1-(1-p)(1-q)}$$

Used is that: $$P(X<Y\mid B_1=0=C_1)=P(X<Y)$$